# Finding X/Y position of Layout Element using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, legend, layouts

Using QGIS 3.10, I am attempting to move a legend in one layout to the same position as a legend in another layout. I just can't figure out how to get the X/Y position of the first legend.

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()

layout1 = projectLayoutManager.layoutByName("layout1")
legend1 = layout1.itemById("legend")
x = (x position of legend?)
y = (y position of legend?)

layout2 = projectLayoutManager.layoutByName("layout2")
legend2 = layout2.itemById("legend")

legend2.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(x,y,QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out myself:

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()

layout1 = projectLayoutManager.layoutByName("layout1")
legend1 = layout1.itemById("legend")
CurrentPositionPoint=legend1.positionWithUnits()

layout2 = projectLayoutManager.layoutByName("layout2")
legend2 = layout2.itemById("legend")
legend2.attemptMove(CurrentPositionPoint)
```

I found the answer [here](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutItemLegend.html):
QGIS API Documentation
-->QgsLayoutItemLegend Class Reference
-->Public Member Functions Inherited from QgsLayoutItem